# sublime text lsp-jdtls cannot resolve imports

Tags: java, sublimetext4

imports like the following:

```
    import org.lwjgl.Version;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
```

have red squiggly lines under them and the error reads cannot resolve import.
It all complies and runs but, there is no autocomplete.
The CLASSPATH is set to '/usr/share/java' and the jars are definitely there.
The latest of LSP and jdtls are installed and Submlie Text is version 4.

I've read all the documentation i can find from sublime text and lsp.

I've tried different build systems, gradle, maven and ant but I don't see how that would make a difference.

What are some likely reasons autocomplete isn't working?
Is lsp actually suppose to do autocomplete if it has access to the jars files?